# Java Sockets : Application with both server and client on same machine

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing an application to send, receive or update files using `Socket`, `ServerSocket` class in Java.
There is one single application which is both server as well as client. I need to get the IP addresses of all other applications running on the same Local Area Network. 
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should use broadcast for this.

For more details take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: This requires the hostname of the server. I don't have a hostname for the server.